# Multiple email addresses on a page using one form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

This is a little tricky for me to explain so I will try my best. I have a page with at list of at least 10 email addresses. Rather than have these as simple "mailto" links, I would like there to be a simple form in a lightbox (this part was easy).

The next part is where I'm finding difficulty. I need to figure out how to not only how to store each email address in a variable, but also to have the form send to the email address that was clicked (if a@a.com is clicked, the form would send to that address, and so on.)

I've seen it done before so I know it's possible, I just don't know where to start. Thanks!

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value="foo@example.com" />foo@example.com`.

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to achieve. Could you post your HTML and JS code.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... Sending an email _through_ your website requires a server-side solution, browsers themselves cannot send emails.

Comment: Do you know how to send an email to ONE recipient using PHP?  If so, please post that part to give people a base to help you from.

Comment: You could try something to the affect of `$user = array("email_1@example.com", "email_2@example.com");` then `foreach($user as $to){ mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); }` that's a quick way that I use just for kicks. There are many other ways of doing this. Just Google "**email array foreach php**" and you're bound to get hits.

Comment: This is all done server side. Some email address dropdown is selected, form is posted, php script pulls email dropdown value from $_GET|$_POST, php sends email on its way. Where's the problem?

Comment: @gwillie Actually using a dropdown would require a multi-select option, which I doubt is what the OP's goal is. Using checkboxes would be a better way to go about it (and easier), as stated by `Marc B` and using a `foreach` in conjunction. *"how to store each email address"*

Comment: @Fred ii- I hope no one is suggesting to store email addresses exposed to the www!

Comment: @gwillie I hope not also (lol) [my example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545644/multiple-email-addresses-on-a-page-using-one-form?noredirect=1#comment29001506_19545644) is meant to be stored inside a PHP handler where emails won't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like...

```
<!-- Your contact form -->
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="emailto" name="emailto" value="">

    <!-- Rest of your form -->
</form>

<!-- Your email address triggers -->
<span class="contacttrigger">a@a.com</span>

<!-- The script -->
<script>
$(".contacttrigger").click(function(){
    $("#emailto").val($(this).html());
    // Show your lightbox now
});
</script>
```

Obviously on the server side you would need to have validation in place to make sure the `emailto` is a valid email address that the form is allowed to send to